# Why does indexing array with an array return two rows?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I'm learning some basic of indexing in numpy. I don't understand why

```py
a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]])
b = a[[1,2]]

pprint(b)
```

gives

```
[[3 4]
 [5 6]]
```

Comment: What were you expecting? `a[2,1]` is an element, because it indexes both rows and columns.  It can also be written as `a[(2,1)]`.  Here the distinction between list and tuple is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a[[1, 2]]` specifies to return the **second** (index `1`) and **third** (index `2`) rows of the array.

`[1, 2]` is the indexer. If you wanted to get the first (index `0`) *column* of the array, you would use a similar indexer, only passing it to the second position:

```
>>> a[:, [0]]
array([[1],
       [3],
       [5]])
```

The `:` basically means "just select all the rows", and `[0]` means "select the 0th column".

Comment: So can I say that `a[[1,2]]` implicitly mean `a[[1,2], :]`?

Comment: @Rainning Yes, you're exactly right.

Comment: It's actually *way* more complicated than this. What you're seeing is a simple-looking special case of the rules for combining NumPy ["basic indexing"](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#basic-indexing) and ["advanced indexing"](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing). If you try to apply this logic to select a subset of rows *and* columns, you'll get [surprising results](https://ideone.com/1Yzk2E) or [weird IndexErrors](https://ideone.com/aid8s4), because the simple-looking special case doesn't generalize like that.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: Really thank you. My NumPy journey started from your comment two days ago. Now I understand both examples and _something_ about advanced indexing.

Comment: To answer myself (i.e. the first comment) to make it a long story: `a[[1,2]]` actually means `a[[1,2], :]` (without the `FutureWarning: ...`, since 1d). And both indexes of `a[[1,2],0]`, `a[[1,2],1]` got _broadcast_ into shape `(2,)`, and then the results _stack along_ the second-axis(i.e. the number of columns increases).

Comment: To be more specific on what I meant _stack along_: `a[[1,2],0]`->`a[[1,2],[0,0]]` gives `[[ a[1,0] ],[ a[2,0] ]] = [ [3], [5] ]`. Then `a[[1,2],1]` gives `[ [4], [6] ]`. Stack along results in `[[3,5], [4,6]]`.